# Perl 1 liner error - does not work - removing multiple strings

Tags: perl

Anyone know a perl one liner to remove words in a file, example I have the following below and it does not work on linux

```
$ ssh root\@$host perl -p -e 's/value1/ /' -e 's/value2/ /' /tmp/file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the contents of `/tmp/file`, instead of just displaying the modified output on stdout, you need to use `perl`'s `-i` option, for "in-place" editing of the file.   See `man perlrun` and search for `-i` for details.

Also, quote your variables when you use them (e.g. `$host`).

BTW, you're changing two different patterns to the same value, a space.
This doesn't need two separate `s///` operations.

```
ssh "root@$host" perl -p -i -e 's/value1|value2/ /' /tmp/file
```

Even if you did need two different operations, you can separate them with a semi-colon (`;`).

```
ssh "root@$host" perl -p -i -e 's/value1/foo/;s/value2/bar/' /tmp/file
```

If you want to make a backup copy of the original file, `-i` takes an optional suffix.  e.g.

```
ssh "root@$host" perl -p -i.bak -e 's/value1|value2/ /' /tmp/file
```

`/tmp/file` will be copied to `/tmp/file.bak` before being edited by perl.

---

You could do this just as easily, and slightly faster (probably not noticable, unless run many times in a loop), with `sed`, which also has an equivalent `-i` option.

From `man sed`:

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)

```
ssh "root@$host" sed -i -e 's/value1\|value2/ /' /tmp/file
```

or with sed's `-E` option for Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)

```
ssh "root@$host" sed -i -E -e 's/value1|value2/ /' /tmp/file
```

BTW, you can separate multiple sed commands with a `;` just like in perl.